# Ubuntu 64 bit version

Tags: linux, ubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is 64 bit Ubuntu not recomended for daily usage?](https://superuser.com/questions/175233/why-is-64-bit-ubuntu-not-recomended-for-daily-usage)

I have a 64 bit PC.
I want to install Linux (as a second OS).
I was thinking Ubuntu, but in the download link it mentions that the 32-bit version is the recommended one.
Is there a problem with 64 bit? Should I just download the recommended version and stay away from 64-bit?

Comment: I never had any problems, but we had lots of similar questions, so take a look. Also, there's 64bit Flash player now available, so the main problem is solved.

Comment: @AndrejaKo:The answer in your post is strange to me.Just because of flash player they do not mark the 64-bit version recommendedI mean why is this not mentioned in the download site?

Comment: @user65971 There are always some old proprietary programs which could cause problems and similar, but the Flash player is **very** important to a large number of users and it has been a major problems for quite some time. First there wasn't any 64bit flash, so there had to be workarounds, then there was 64bit Flash, but Adobe pulled it, now it's available again and so on. Also available versions of 64bit Flash are all marked as BETA, so that could be another point.